# How do you get your IDE to recognize usages from PHP factories that use strings to instantiate a class?

Tags: php, factory-pattern, solid-principles

I love how in most cases you can use a Factory Pattern to help you adhere to SOLID development. The one thing I don't quite understand is how to get your IDE to recognize usages when you build your factories. For example:

```
<?php

class ProductFactory {

  public static function build($product_type, $name) {
    $productClass = 'Product' . ucwords($product_type);
    if (class_exists($productClass)) {
      return new $productClass($name);
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Invalid product type given.");
    }
  }

}
```

My IDE does not recognize $productClass as a usage for a given class because it can be an instance of multiple classes. I understand that. However, how can I tell my IDE where to find these usages? Do I need to list ALL of them in the docblock?

```
/**
 * @var ProductSofa $class
 * @var ProductChair $class
 */
```

Is that the only way?

Comment: If you're using PHPStorm or IntelliJ IDEA, [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata) and [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7251) can help.

Comment: @DCoder this is awesome! You should post that as an Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using docblocks in order to typehint your class properties is the best way to handle with this. I've been using zend2 for quite a while now, and other than typehinting class constructor parameters, adding a docblock to each property is the only way, because usually when you get an instance from a factory, you use some kind of ServiceLocator that by parameter, receives a name of a factory you want to instantiate, and its a string, so your IDE has no way to relate that string to an actual class.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no standard PHPDoc for this feature, you'll need an IDE-specific solution. If you're using PHPStorm or IntelliJ IDEA, they have [built-in support for documenting factory method return types](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata), which can be further enhanced by [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7251).